# Lipschitz functions that map $0$ to $0$ are convergence-preserving

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know convergence-preserving functions have been discussed a fair amount in the past; however, I was a looking at [another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337042/sum-a-n-converges-iff-sum-fa-n-converges/1337057#1337057), and I saw the following result: if $f$ is Lipschitz and $f(0)=0$, then $\sum |a_n| <\infty \Rightarrow \sum |f(a_n)|<\infty$. How exactly would I go about proving this statement? I'm also guessing from other posts that this is a sufficient but not necessary condition?

Edit: made it absolute convergence instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT

$|f(a_n)-f(0)| \leq M|a_n|$ for some $M>0$

The converse is not true.I'm sure you can find a counterexample.

Comment: Oh, I see, hahaha. I feel silly now.

Answer (score 0):

It's not true at all, unless you assume $a_n \ge 0$.  The problem is that if $\sum_n a_n $ converges conditionally, $\sum_n f(a_n)$ can diverge even though $|f(a_n)| \le M |a_n|$.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I meant absolute convergence! I'll make an edit.

Comment: concrete example: $a_n=(-1)^n/n$, $f(x)=|x|$